# Dynamic Polymorphism's weird output

Tags: c#, inheritance, dynamic, polymorphism

I am unable to understand the output. I have following two classes,

```
class A
{
    public int i = 1;

    public virtual void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am A");
    } 
}

class B:A
{
    public int i =2 ; 

    public override void Print()
    {
        i++;
        Console.WriteLine("I am B");
    }

}
```

Now, when i run the following code,

```
A a1 = new PolymorphismInDepth.B();
        a1.Print();
        Console.WriteLine(a1.i);
```

I get the following output,

---

I am B

1

---

why do I get 1? Why not 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base class object `a1` is pointing to the Derived object in memory. Hence `a1.Print()` will call the methods reference, i.e., `B().Print()` but you cannot access `B().i` using this `A().i`.

You need to cast it:

```
Console.WriteLine(((B)a1).i);
```

You are confused because you used same variable names. Try this out:

```
class A
{
    public int ai = 1;

    public virtual void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am A");
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public int bi = 2;

    public override void Print()
    {
        bi++;
        Console.WriteLine("I am B");
    }

}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    A a1 = new B();
    a1.Print();
    Console.WriteLine(a1.ai);
    Console.WriteLine(((B)a1).bi);
    Console.Read();
}
```

Trying to access `bi` like this should give you a compile time error:

```
Console.WriteLine(a1.bi); //ERROR: 'A' does not contain a definition for 'bi'...
```

**Update:**

To add on to the answer - an implementation like this where you override the base class member variable behavior can also be achieved:

```
class A
{
    private int i = 1;
    public virtual int I
    {
        get { return i; }
    }

    public virtual void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am A");
    }
}

class B : A
{
    private int i = 2;

    public override int I
    {
        get { return i; }
    }
    public override void Print()
    {
        i++;
        Console.WriteLine("I am B");
    }

}


A a1 = new B();
a1.Print();
Console.WriteLine(a1.I);
Console.WriteLine(((B)a1).I);
```

Output:

> I am B
>
> 3
>
> 3

Comment: please elaborate properly for "your B().i hides the base class member A().i" such that it will be clear and descriptive

Comment: You could say more clearly that B.i is a new variable, unrelated to A.i. It just happens to have the same name (that you are addressing well by renaming).

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider - i thought over it, actually its not that simple. The issue did not happen just because of the names being same, the issue is that the Interface provided by `A` cannot access items in `B` at compile time. The OP's assumption was that having the same variable name will give access to the derived object's variable - not necessarily anything to do with variable name.

Comment: Well, "the OP's [erroneous] assumption [...] that having the same variable name will give access to the derived object's variable" is exactly the point. The variables are completely unrelated. He could have named B's member `k` instead without changing the semantics (as you demonstrate), but he *thought* that the naming does magically connect the two unrelated members. It doesn't. And of course can the "interface provided by `A`" access items in `B`, which can succinctly be demonstrated by calling `a1.Print()`. One just cannot override variables. (One can override properties though.)

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider i think OP's aware that those variables are unrelated hence OP's expectation of variation in output. OP could have marked base `i` virtual if OP wanted member polymorphism.

Comment: ["The virtual keyword is used to modify a method, property, indexer, or event declaration "](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4.aspx). Not a variable declaration. And no, I don't think the OP is aware that the variables are unrelated. If he wonders that `Console.WriteLine(a1.i);` outputs `1`  although he incremented `B.i`, he must think they are the same. If they had different names, that would surely not occur to him. Hence my assumption that he is under the impression that the name `i`  does the same magic for a variable that the name `Print`  does for a function. It doesn't.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider - what the OP might have thought is highly subjective.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Sadiq has said. If you mark your classes as public and build you see that editor is indicating something for variable i in class B. It says that you are hiding base member I and should override with `new` keyword.

So, if you remove public int i =2 ; from class B then you get output as 2 as you are modifying base variable. But if you declare new i in B then you are creating separate scope of new i in B.

So with current code if you put debugger on line `Console.WriteLine(a1.ai);`
it clearly shows two i variables one with value 1 and other with value 2. Value 2 is for type B. So you will get 2 only when you are referring i from instance of B.

Hope this clears doubt.